# Database tables for QuickFIX/J

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

QuickFIX/J includes SQL scripts to create four database tables:

- `sessions`
- `messages`
- `messages_log`
- `event_log`

I cannot find any documentation that describes the purpose of each of these tables.

What are they for, when are they written to, do any of them grow indefinitely, etc...

Comment: It's misleading to say that QuickFIX/J requires four database tables. Database usage is optional in QuickFIX/J (separately optional for session state and logs) and not recommended if you have even modest performance requirements. The session state tables will be cleared at the start of each session. The log tables will grow indefinitely so you'll want some type of archive approach at some point.

Comment: Thanks Frank. This is a good point. Question updated.

Answer (score 15):

Some tables are used for the *store*, others are used for *logging* (the `*_log` tables.) A *store* is required for QuickFIX/J to operate (it tracks session state and supports resends of messages) whereas the log is optional.

---

### `sessions`

This table tracks active FIX sessions. Sessions have a composite key of the eight values shown in the `primary key` declaration below.

`creation_time` is used to determine which session this applies to.

`*_seqnum` columns track the current sequence numbers for the session, and are used for reliability along with resend requests.

```
create table sessions (
  beginstring  char(8) not null,
  sendercompid varchar(64) not null,
  sendersubid  varchar(64) not null,
  senderlocid  varchar(64) not null,
  targetcompid varchar(64) not null,
  targetsubid  varchar(64) not null,
  targetlocid  varchar(64) not null,
  session_qualifier varchar(64) not null,
  creation_time timestamp not null,
  incoming_seqnum integer not null,
  outgoing_seqnum integer not null,
  primary key (beginstring, sendercompid, sendersubid, senderlocid,
               targetcompid, targetsubid, targetlocid, session_qualifier)
);
```

---

### `messages`

This table provides a persistent store of the FIX messages sent during an active session. If the party being communicated with requires messages to be resent, QuickFIX/J will use this table to determine the content of the messages.

At the start of each session, messages for the `session_qualifier` are removed. Thus this table will not grow indefinitely and the upper bound of its size depends upon how many messages may be sent during a session.

```
create table messages (
  beginstring char(8) not null,
  sendercompid varchar(64) not null,
  sendersubid varchar(64) not null,
  senderlocid varchar(64) not null,
  targetcompid varchar(64) not null,
  targetsubid varchar(64) not null,
  targetlocid varchar(64) not null,
  session_qualifier varchar(64) not null,
  msgseqnum integer not null,
  message text not null,
  primary key (beginstring, sendercompid, sendersubid, senderlocid,
               targetcompid, targetsubid, targetlocid, session_qualifier,
               msgseqnum)
);
```

---

### `messages_log`

QuickFIX/J can log all inbound/outbound messages to a database. The table is write-only from the perspective of the library, so it is up to you if you wish to use this table or not.

Different tables may be specified in config for inbound and outbound message logs. By default, all messages are logged to a single table.

```
create sequence messages_log_sequence;

create table messages_log (
  id integer default nextval('messages_log_sequence'),
  time timestamp not null,
  beginstring char(8) not null,
  sendercompid varchar(64) not null,
  sendersubid varchar(64) not null,
  senderlocid varchar(64) not null,
  targetcompid varchar(64) not null,
  targetsubid varchar(64) not null,
  targetlocid varchar(64) not null,
  session_qualifier varchar(64),
  text text not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

---

### `event_log`

A log of events is written to this table. Examples include:

> Session FIX.4.2:FOO->BAR schedule is daily, 07:00:00-UTC - 21:00:00-UTC
>
> Created session: FIX.4.2:FOO->BAR
>
> Initiated logon request
>
> Received logon

```
create sequence event_log_sequence;

create table event_log (
  id integer default nextval('event_log_sequence'),
  time timestamp not null,
  beginstring char(8) not null,
  sendercompid varchar(64) not null,
  sendersubid varchar(64) not null,
  senderlocid varchar(64) not null,
  targetcompid varchar(64) not null,
  targetsubid varchar(64) not null,
  targetlocid varchar(64) not null,
  session_qualifier varchar(64),
  text text not null,
  primary key (id)
);
```

---

As @DumbCoder points out, the table names may be customised via config.

Comment: Note that the SQL scripts for different database types are here: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master/src/sql/